# Simple word comparison in C

Tags: c

I've just written a fairly simple program in C to find `smallest word` and `largest word`. I have 3 variables as follow:

```
char smallest[20]; // smallest word
char largest[20]; // largest word
char word[20]; // the word entered by user
```

Then I show a prompt to user to enter any word he want:

```
while (1) {
  printf("Enter a word: ");
  while((ch = getchar()) != '\n') {
    word[i++] = ch;
  }
}
```

Then I will compare `word` with both `smallest` and `largest` in order to achieve the result which is to find smallest and largest word among user entered words.

```
if (strcmp(word, smallest) < 0) {
  strcpy(smallest, word);
}

if (strcmp(word, largest) > 0) {
  strcpy(largest, word);
}
```

And finally the program will terminate if user just enter without typing any word.
The program find `largest` word correctly but my problem is with finding `smallest` word.

Here is the entire program if you want copy/paste to test it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

  char smallest[20] = "";
  char largest[20] = "";
  char word[20] = "";

  while (1) {

      int i = 0;
      char ch;

      strcpy(word, "");

      printf("Enter a word: ");
      while((ch = getchar()) != '\n') {
        word[i++] = ch;
      }

      if (strcmp(word, smallest) < 0) {
        strcpy(smallest, word);
      }

      if (strcmp(word, largest) > 0) {
        strcpy(largest, word);
      }


    if (strlen(word) == 0) break;
  }

  printf("Smallest word: %s\n", smallest);
  printf("Largest word: %s\n", largest);

  return 0;

}
```

Would you please tell me how to modify it to find both `smallest` and `largest` word correctly.

Comment: Is char largest = ""; a typo? Do you mean char largest[20] = "";?

Comment: this is what I don't know how and when to initialize them correctly

Comment: You need to copy the first word entered into smallest directly, because the empty string compares 'smaller' than any other string, so you've initialized `smallest_word` to the smallest possible word.  You could use a more complicated initialization, such as `memset(smallest, '\xFF', sizeof(smallest)-1); smallest[sizeof(smallest)-1] = '\0';` instead; that's the 'largest' possible word (null-terminated string) that fits in a 20-byte buffer.  You also have a problem if the code encounters EOF; your loop continues and you'd have to interrupt this program to stop it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I have problem with initializing `smallest` and `largest` correctly. thanks for your good point

Comment: 1) best initialization method char variable[20] = {'\0'};  However, it needs to be re-initialized before saving a new word, (probably by memset()) so there is no trash left over in the buffer.  2) the loop to read a word has no size limitation so if the user enters a word, more than 19 characters, a buffer overflow will occur, which can/will lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: the code needs to inform the user 1( what they are expected to enter and 2) the 19char size limitation

Comment: the code is comparing (unterminated) strings alphabetically, do you want to compare alphabetically or by string length?  The lack of proper string termination is a problem that can/will lead to undefined behaviour and (probably) a set fault event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This loop has at least four problems:

```
  while((ch = getchar()) != '\n') {
    word[i++] = ch;
  }
```

First of all it can overwrite memory beyond the array and secondly you have to append the string with the terminating zero.  Also you are saving results into a `char` but `getchar()` returns an `int`, and you are not testing for `EOF` but you should (and it is crucial that you use `int ch;` so you can test accurately for `EOF`).

Use function `fgets` instead of `getchar` (but remember it includes the newline in its output).

Or rewrite the loop the following way

```
  while( i < 19 && (ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
    word[i++] = ch;
  }

  word[i] = '\0';
```

Take into account that it seems there are typos in your code. At least I do not see declarations of 
`smallest_word` and `largest_word`.

Answer (score 3):

One of your problems is, that the empty string compares smaller than all other strings, so your code to find the smallest string correctly returns the empty string with which it was initialized.

Since there is no special string that compares greater than all other strings, you need to use the first string you get as the initialization:

```
for(int i = 0; ; i++) {

    //code to read a string

    if(!i) {
        //First time: the current string is definitely the smallest and the largest one.
        strcpy(smallest, word);
        strcpy(largest, word);
    } else {
        if (strcmp(word, smallest_word) < 0) strcpy(smallest, word);
        if (strcmp(word, largest_word) > 0) strcpy(largest, word);
    }
}
```

---

Sidenote:
It is generally not a good idea to use fixed size buffers to store strings from user input. Sooner or later you *will* get an input that exceeds your buffer size. Better use dynamically allocated strings. In your case you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  char* smallest = NULL, *largest = NULL, *word = NULL;

  for(int i = 0; ; i++) {
      printf("Enter a word: ");
      size_t bufferSize = 0;
      ssize_t stringSize = getline(&word, &bufferSize, stdin);    //this returns a malloced string with the entire line in word
      if(stringSize <= 0) break;    //This also catches end of file.
      word[stringSize - 1] = 0;    //getline() includes the newline in the string, remove it

      if(!i) {
          //First time: the current string is definitely the smallest and the largest one.
          smallest = strdup(word);
          largest = strdup(word);
      } else {
          if (strcmp(word, smallest) < 0) {
              free(smallest);
              smallest = strdup(word);
          }
          if (strcmp(word, largest) > 0) {
              free(largest);
              largest = strdup(word);
          }
      }

      free(word);
  }

  printf("Smallest word: %s\n", smallest);
  printf("Largest word: %s\n", largest);

  free(smallest);
  free(largest);

  return 0;

}
```

Users can throw strings at this code that are megabytes in length, and it will handle them with ease.

Comment: getline() is not available everywhere

Comment: getline() usually is implemented to include the trailing newline then a '\0' bite.  The code might want to replace the newline with '\0'

Comment: @user3629249 Good point. I fixed the code. And yes, `getline()` and `strdup()` conform to the POSIX-2008 standard, which is not implemented everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Use `strlen()` instead of `strcmp()` to see which word is longer.
`strcmp()` will compare if both strings are the same, `strlen()` will get the length.